# unable to use Fiddler installed on VM to intercept traffic from an external ios device

Tags: proxy, fiddler

I have fiddler2 installed on my windows vm. I would like to set this up to intercept network calls from my iOS device. I was following this documentation http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configureforios but I could'nt figure out a solution yet. (I'm not in any corp firewalls).

note: Fiddler works as expected when i work with simulator.

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't explained what specifically isn't working. Follow the steps here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/SsZnGxdxklg and update your question.

What VM technology are you using?

Note: For this to work, your VM needs to be configured with a public IP address; see, for instance: http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/14-01-15/running-fiddler-in-virtualbox-on-mac

Comment: I'm using VMware fusion. I could setup fiddler to intercept the traffic from my host(mac). But however, I could'nt setup fiddler to intercept traffic from an external device.

Comment: If you can capture traffic from the mac but not an external device, the problem is either the device is using the wrong IP or the Mac's firewall is in the way.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I could get this working by changing my vm's network adapter settings from NAT to Bridged.

Comment: Eric, the above setup works perfectly fine. But now I'm trying this under CORP firewalls. Is there a workaround for this.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say "trying this under CORP firewalls" or what "workaround" you're hoping for. Your best bet would be to go to the Fiddler discussion forum (see the Help) and write up a post describing exactly what you're trying to do, and specifically what is not working when you try it.

Comment: [Fiddler] The connection to '127.0.0.1' failed. 
Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080 --- getting this error i followed as per your instruction on virtualbox not capturing the application running on local

Comment: @shams Rather than piling into a comment field, you should open a new question with details about your configuration and what you've tried. Among other possibilities, Fiddler doesn't run on port 8080 by default.